# Video Caption keeps lapping into the Video

Tags: html, reactjs, web, web-deployment

[image]

Hey  Guys   so i have been programming for a month now and i am working on a Webpage 
So basically there is a Video starting at the very Top of the Webpage and underneath there is a Caption.
In the Webbrowser everything is fine and fits.
But if you look at the Page from different Devices with different Screen Sizes the Text beneath the Caption tends to  **leap**  upward into the Video.
Is there a way to make the Video as an Object which doesnt allow Texts or other onejcts to leap into it? 
 i Mean there has to be a Way to make Borders between those 2 Objects which work on all Screen Resolutions. 
Greetings Mattia


Tell me if you need a Screenshot or a Code

Answer (score 0):

You must to create css adapting to another screen size (smartphone, tablet ...) this is done using media queries for example:

```
#myDiv {
  margin-top: 20px;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  #myDiv {
    margin-top: 150px;
  }
}
```

The part: `(max-width: 992px)` is used to define from which screen size the applicable rule.

Comment: Hey there thanks for your Answer 
i feel like on the Mobile Side it made things better but on the Desktop side it made things actually worse 
The Caption leaps a lot easier now into the Video 
i mean there has to be a way to tell the <h3> simply not to go into the Video

Comment: The media screen is not supposed to impact general CSS, it is normally isolated and only activates when the condition is true (eg when the specified size is reached).

Could you send your css?

Comment: ay man i got some issues in term of replaying to your Answer 
Since Stackoverflow does not recognize my Css-Code as Code

Comment: Is there a private Message Section where i can share my Css-Code with you?